# asp.net повторное использование aspx страниц в другом проекте

Tags: .net, asp.net

Пишу сайт на asp.net Web Forms. Портал состоит из пяти проектов. Первый - названный "Commun" (или "общий" на русском) содержит только логику и компилируется как dll. Остальные используют эту dll  в references проекта. Остальные четыре проекта это четыре разных подпортала: один для клиентов, другой для администраторов проекта, третий еще для кого-нибудь и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли как-то при такой архитектуре использовать aspx страницу из другого проекта? К примеру проект InterfaceInstruction имеет страницу `Mypage.aspx`,  как ее вызвать из друго проекта в том же Solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете преобразовать ваши страницы в `ascx`, что будет правильнее в контексте общего использования. Выделите все общие блоки в проект *CommonControls*, преобразовав их в контролы.

Страницы в Ваших проектах это некие конечные представления, которые используют общую логику и контролы (возможно с общей информацией) и частные данные и логику.